# Renew provisioning distribution profiles

Tags: ios, certificate, ios-provisioning

My provisioning distribution profiles expired today,
so when I press renew button in Xcode organiser I see alert window with *"No value was provided for the parameter 'deviceIds'"*.

If I go to iOS Provisioning Portal and try to renew there,
then when I press the button renew — I switched to the development tab. If I go back to provision tab — I still see renew button, nothing changed.

[image]

Upd.: Today I see

[image]

Comment: Sent an email to Apple Support, will see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that distribution certificate expired also, I found that occasionally.
After I submitted a new one, I was able to modify and get new profiles.
However, I still wasn't able to renew it through Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Once again check under Provisioning> Distribution you have Download & edit option.if still there is no update means check your email apple send you renew information.

Comment: No, it's always "Renew". And no emails from Apple.